# Autocomplete - how to send the ID instead a text

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I have following set up of `autocomplete` part my app:

**controller**

```
  autocomplete :user, :phone, :display_value => :funky_method, :extra_data => [:first_name, :last_name]
```

**model (user.rb)**

```
  def funky_method
      "#{self.first_name} #{self.last_name}"
  end
```

**view**

```
<%= f.autocomplete_field :user_id, autocomplete_user_phone_invoices_path %>
```

When I start to write a phone number into this `autocomplete input`, so I will get an offer of a users who have the number. That's right.
But when I send this form, so in the `autocomplete input` will be send the name of selected user (by his phone number).

But I try to send instead a name of the user his ID -- I have read about [id_element](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete), but I still can't find the right way, how to do it.

Could anyone give me a tip, please, about this problem?

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you seen this railscast? http://railscasts.com/episodes/102-auto-complete-association

Comment: Yea, I have seen this one, but this is the other gem - specifically this one: [rails3-jquery-autocomplete](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete)